# Getting undefined when using function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a function that used reduce() method to count the number of items in an array and return the length of that array.

This is what I have so far:

```
function len(items) {
    items.reduce(function(prev, curr, index){
        return index+1;
    });
}

let nums = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(len(nums));
```

Whenever I try to run this code, in the console on my browser I get the message 'undefined'. I think I defined my function properly, so I don't know why its not being called or outputting any values. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong or if my logic is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to return

```
function len(items) {
    return items.reduce(function(prev, curr, index){
        return index+1;
    });
}
```

or simply

```
function len(items) {
    return items.length;
}
```

Comment: I need to use reduce in order to get the length.

Comment: @flamedra then you can choose first option I have mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function len(items) {
    return items.reduce(function(prev, curr, index){
        return index+1;
    });
}

let nums = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(len(nums));
```

Comment: This is working. Can you please explain whey I need to return both the reduce method when I'm also returning inside the function?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
function len(items) {
  if(items){                 //error handle
    return items.length;

  }
       return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I need to use the reduce method to get the length.